# Quasi-automatic import realization from *csv

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

My problem is that I have to realize an easy-refreshable database system. At start, I have 2 tables imported from *csv format, and I need to restructure them and make certain new tables. I also have to add ID-s to certain properties, to make searching more faster (it is going to contain loads of data, and is going to be refreshed almost every day). It is going to contain millions of records with many rows. My first question is how to import? I need only selective rows from the original file, but the *csv layout will remain the same.

My second question is how to create indexes *in the new tables* (that were generated by the queries mentioned) to certain properties to make searching faster?

If you think, my questions are not exact enough, please comment, and I'm going to answer you with my best knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the CSV file can be imported into a single temporary table you can then use a series of append queries to push relevant details to separate tables to normalise your data.  For example, if one column in your CSV file contains country names then create a table (**tbl_Countries**) which has an autonumber as its key field and the country field set to no duplicates.  Append the countries to this table:  **INSERT INTO tbl_Countries (sCountry) SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM MyCSVTable **.

Comment: Once all fields have been normalised that can be normalised - push the remaining data to your main data table and use joins to bring back the index number from each table rather than the country name.  (Hope that all made sense).